# Unity5. Animation will only run once

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

if I currently press on a UI button a disabled GameObject gets enabled. But when I attach a Animator to the GameObject (with a animation on it) it will only run the first time I enable the GameObject, but I want it to play the Animation every time the GameObject gets enabled. (The first time you press the button, the GameObject gets enabled and when you press it a second time it gets disabled)

Do you have any ideas how I can do that?

Comment: is the animation in loop?

Comment: @CristianoSoleti no its not

Comment: but when i put it in a loop it will never end (its a fade in effect)

Comment: if you want to have an animation play every time the object is setActive(true) use the play on awake toggle on the animation component. That way there's no need to call any animation, all you need to do is setActive(true) and setActive(false). If you want a fade in fade out animation though, I recommend you use the animatorcontroller and setTriggers accordingly.

Comment: @Alox Im sorry but on the animation component isn't play on awake togge

Comment: @Alox I cant find a play on awake toggle (Sorry for my spelling)

Comment: try to put your code in OnEnable()

Comment: @pasotee do you mean like that : private void OnEnable()
{ anim.Play("name");}

Comment: @OlivervanVelzen yes, did it work?

Comment: @OlivervanVelzen sorry, that'd be play automatically on the Animation component if you were to use a legacy Animation instead of an Animator on the gameobject.

Comment: @pasotee no its not :(

Comment: @Alox im using an animator component

Comment: @Alox But what do you mean with setTriggers ? (Im pretty new to unity and c#) And Thanks for your help btw.

Comment: @OlivervanVelzen If you plan on using an Animator, use the triggers to play certain animations. Triggers can be found in the Animator tab, bottom left. Once you've created some ie: fadeIn fadeOut, make a transition from one animation to the next and instead of the exit time condition select the appropriate trigger option. Then in the code, call animator.SetTrigger("fadeIn"); and it will play the said animation.

Comment: @OlivervanVelzen here's a tutorial for using animator.. https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/animation/animator-controller

Comment: @alox Im sorry but I cant find any trigger options in the animator tab. There are only Layers and Parameters

Comment: @OlivervanVelzen click the + next to parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just trigger the animation everytime you click the button.

Comment: im sorry im pretty new to c# and unity could you explain me how to to it ? and thanks for your fast answer

Comment: Something like:
anim.SetBool("walk", buttonState);
You set the parameter walk into the animator.